# Access exposure control in USB webcam

Tags: raspbian, usb, camera

I am trying to control exposure value for USB webcam connected to raspberry pi. Exposure is not listed in --list-controls for my camera, however exposure control was previously done for windows desktop by:

```
CamControl.Set(CamControlProperty.Exposure, ManualExposure, CameraControlFlags.Manual);
```

Is there any python libraries(similar to picamera) which may help me with that or other way to control exposure? Thanks.

Comment: Did the manufacturer provide a windows driver?  If so then that's what provides the additional functionality there.

Comment: @goldilocks, thanks for reply. I am not sure what you mean, but the same camera has been used as sensor for windows desktop app(standard usb webcam driver and directshowlib allow to access exposure and autofocus controls). I am not familiar with Linux and its libraries to implement this functionality. Now I am trying to access these controls using OpenCV on Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by using uvcdynctrl control tool instead of v4l2. For my webcam exposure can be changed by uvcdynctrl -s "Exposure (Absolute)".